# What's internal mechanism of decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator

I know that the decorator is a function that takes another function and extends its behavior.
In the example below, I previously assume that **test()** now is effectively equivalent to **decorator(test)()**.

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        return res
    return wrapper

@decorator
def test():
    pass
```

However, after adding a function attribute in the decorator and run both **test()** and **decorator(test)()**, the results are different. It seems that in the case of **decorator(test)()**, the decorator function is indeed ran so that num is reset; when using @decorator instead, the decorator function is not ran as I expected?

```
def decorator(func):
    decorator.num = 0
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        ...
        return res
    return wrapper

@decorator
def test():
    pass
   
def test2():
    pass

decorator.num = 5
test()
print(decorator.num)

decorator.num = 5
decorator(test2)()
print(decorator.num)

---------------------
5
0
```

Comment: The decorator is applied at function definition time, not function call time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion stems from *when* the decorator runs. The syntax

```
@decorator
def foo(): ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def foo(): ...

foo = decorator(foo)
```

That is, *immediately* after the function is defined, the decorator is called on it, *and* the result of calling the decorator is assigned back to the original function name. It's called only once, at definition time, not once per function call.

The same is true of classes. The syntax

```
@decorator
class Foo: ...
```

is equivalent to

```
class Foo: ...

Foo = decorator(Foo)
```

Comment: To be clear: `decorator` is called once at function definition time, the inner returned `wrapper` is called at every function call…